# async_resolve and async_connect params lifetime

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I would like to know what is lifetime of objects passed to mentioned methods.

## async_resolve

```
ip::basic_resolver::async_resolve(const query & q, ResolveHandler handler);
```

(1) Do I need to keep resolver alive until handler is called? (yes)
(2) Does async_resolve copy `query` object? (I am passing one created on the stack - yes)

```
{
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(host_, port_);
   resolver_.async_resolve(query, );
}
```

(3) Is `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator` returned in handler by value? (yes)

## async_connect

```
template<..> void async_connect(basic_socket<Protocol, SocketService> & s,
Iterator begin, ComposedConnectHandler h);
```

(4) Is `begin` passed by value? (yes)
(5) Do I need to keep `resolver` alive? (no)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Boost.Asio, the general rule is that:

- Arguments passed by const-reference or value are copied.  If supported, they may be moved.
- Arguments passed by non-const-reference are required to remain valid until the synchronous operation completes or until the asynchronous operation's handler is called.

When there are exceptions to the rule, the documentation will indicate it, such as the case of the *buffers* argument for [`boost::asio::async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html), which must remain valid until the handler is called.

---

For [`ip::basic_resolver`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver.html):

- As with other service objects, if the service object is destroyed with outstanding asynchronous operations, then the asynchronous operation handlers will be invoked with `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.  If you do not want to manage the lifespan of the service object, then manage it with a [`shard_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) and bind a copy of the `shared_ptr` into the handler.
- For [`async_resolve`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve/overload1.html) the `query` object is passed by const-reference and eventually copied in the underlying operation's constructor ([`resolve_endpoint_op`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/asio/detail/resolve_endpoint_op.hpp)).  This also permits using a temporary `query` object as well.

  ```
  {
    typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query;
    resolver_.async_resolve(query(host_, port_), );
  }
  ```
- [`async_resolve`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve/overload1.html) expects *handler* to meet the [ResolverHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ResolveHandler.html) requirements.  It documents that the *iterator* argument is taken by value.

For [`boost::asio::async_connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect.html):

- Per the documentation, the *begin* argument is passed by value.
- The `resolver` does not need to remain alive because the iterator's have shared ownership of the query results.  While not in the documentation, the [`ip::basic_resolver_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_iterator.hpp) maintains a `shared_ptr` to a `std::vector` of [`ip::basic_resolver_entry`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_entry.hpp) objects.  The `basic_resolver_entry` objects have member variables for endpoint, host name, and service name.