# boost.asio boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve doesn't work

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I Followed the Boost.Asio toturial to implement a simple TCP client, but I'm blocked at the first step, `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve` doesn't work, the ResolverHandler never be called:

```
    void client::start()
    {
        socket_.reset(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service_));
        // Start an asynchronous resolve to translate the server and service names
        // into a list of endpoints.
        tcp::resolver::query query(server_address_, server_port_);
        resolver_.async_resolve(query,
            boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, 
            shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
    }
```

As the source code shown above, I create an `io_service`, a `socket`, a `resolver` and a resolver `query` object, then call `resolver_.async_resolve()` method, but the ResolverHandler `client::handle_resolve` almost never be called, sometimes at the first time the application starting up, the ResolverHandler may be called one or two times, but then nothing more.

I read the official documentation, but find nothing. Any suggestion?

Comment: server_address_ & server_port_ should be available, such as "localhost" & "25166".

Comment: I think your `tcp::resolver::query` is being destroyed on function exit.

Comment: @PSIAlt `async_resolve()` [copies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12802484/283302) the `tcp::resolver::query` object

Comment: @Fan Yang post a [sscce](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem. I'd like to see your `client::handle_resolve()` method. Also note that `async_resolve()` is typically [emulated](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html) on most (all?) platforms with a thread per `io_service`.

Comment: If the completion handler doesn't get invoked -- most likely you don't run `io_service` correctly. Show `io_service`-related code.

Comment: @IgorR. Right!  I used one io_service for a TCP server and a TCP client at the same time, so the later TCP client was blocked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IgorR. Make your comment an answer

Comment: @Sam Miller ok, done. Although, I don't like such vague answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the completion handler doesn't get invoked -- most likely you don't run `io_service` correctly: eg. its `run` loop might be blocked by some other handler that didn't return, or it might have exited due to lack of work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
void SSLSocket::Connect(SSLSocket* psSLS, const string& serverPath, const string& port)
{
   boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> IOServ(new boost::asio::io_service);
   // Create the resolver and query objects to resolve host name in serverPath to an ip address.
   IOService = IOServ; // IOService defined as a class member in the .h file.
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*IOService);
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(serverPath, port);
   ...
}
```

The above code uses the synchronous method .vs. the asynchronous method that your code is using.  If you want to continue doing it asynchronously, then make the io_service object and query object a class variable.  Also realize that the async_resolve method returns right away without doing anything.  The address gets resolved asynchronously after which your handle_resolve method is called.

Comment: passing a `tcp::resolver::query` with automatic storage duration to `async_resolve()` is [just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12802484/283302), the underlying service will copy the object as necessary.

Comment: Unicode awareness , const by default, auto-ref-counted, pass-by-ref by default, COW by default, to list a few for a good string class.